# Problem with Python nested objects being stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I'm having some trouble with changing the value of a class at runtime and then instantiating it into an object, then storing that object inside of another class and putting that into  python dictionary.

Here is a small code snippet I wrote to illustrate the problem:

```
import unittest

class cls1(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

class cls2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1


class Testdict(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.objs = dict()

    def runTest(self):
        obj2 = cls2()
        obj1 = cls1(cls2())

        self.objs["test1"] = obj1

        self.assertEqual(self.objs["test1"].obj.var, 1)

        cls2.var = 2
        self.assertEqual(cls2.var, 2)
        obj1 = cls1(cls2())

        self.objs["test2"] = obj1

        self.assertEqual(self.objs["test1"].obj.var, 1)
        self.assertEqual(self.objs["test2"].obj.var, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = Testdict()
    d.runTest()
```

Why would cls2 not instantiate with having it's var equal to 2?

I hope this question makes some sense.

Comment: Please give your classes names which Begin with a Capital Letter.  It's much easier for us to read.

Comment: Sorry about that, I usually write pep8 compliant code, I just was trying to write this down in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing can't work.  Ever.

```
class Cls2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
```

That's an instance variable.  It's not a class variable.  You can't access that `.var` with `Cls2.var`  That variable only exists **within** each unique instance of the class.

```
        Cls2.var = 2
```

Does not change the `self.var` instance variable.  That creates a new class variable in the `Cls2` class.

You'd need to do something like this.

```
class Cls2(object):
    default= 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = Cls2.default
```

Now you can do

```
Cls2.default= 2
```

And the rest of whatever it is you're doing should work.

Comment: Thanks S.Lott, I appreciate you typing out an example it makes it very clear what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your test would work if cls2 didn't overwrite cls.var when it is instantiated.

Try this:

```
class cls2(object):

    def __init__(self):
      try:
        self.var
      except:
        self.var = 1
```

The `try` statement just checks to see if you've already set `var`.